# How to design the progress bar facebook login screen and use loader on image downloading

Tags: android

How to implement progress bar in our app like in facebook login  screen (in picture).

[image]

how to show loader like facebook home screen. It need to show the downloading the image in my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ProgressWheel library](https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel) . 
It's easy to use and customizable. 
Samples are also provided in the link above.

Comment: thank you ..Ashraf Bashir .. i will check

Comment: If it works well with you, kindly mark the answer "up" and check it as correct answer too .. enjoy :)

Comment: ok...it is work well .. thank you..